# How to check if user is banned before logging in with PHP

Tags: php

I currently have a login function which works fine however i'm looking to add something into the function so it also checks if the users status is `1`.

`1` = banned

`0` = unbanned

function:

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, status FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) 
            {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

    if(empty($uname) || empty($umail) || empty($upass)){
            $error = "Please enter all fields";
    }


    if($login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass))
    {
        $success = "Logged in successfully, redirecting..";
        header( "refresh:3;url=debits" );
        //$login->redirect('debits');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Incorrect username or password";
    }   
}
```

I tried doing `if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']) && $userRow['status'] == 0)` and I think this works however when I try testing with a banned account, I still receive the error message `Incorrect username or password` when i'd prefer this to be `Your account has been banned`.

Comment: Do you seriously need to return just true or false   in your function. Do this unstead.               If (password verification  &&     userRow['status'] == 0  ){return 'connected'}else if (userRow['status'] == 0){return 'false password '}else {return 'banned'}

Comment: @Machavity I don't think that question is a duplicate of this one. The query the OP is using does not combine both AND and OR.

Comment: @Mike `WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail` and then we add `AND banned = 0` or something similar

Comment: @Machavity But then you're into doing two separate queries, because he wants to  return a different message based on the banned status.

Comment: There are 4 possible outcomes: either the user doesn't exist, the user exists and password is incorrect, the user exists but is banned, or valid login credentials provided and user is not banned. 1 and 2 should have the same error message, 3 should have another error message and 4 should log the user in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return array that contains both booleans of correct password and banned status of the user. Now when validating, check the password correct boolean to know whether user entered correct password or otherwise display incorrect email or password as you are already doing. Now if password is correct you can then check the status boolean to know if user is banned or not and send an appropriate error message.

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, status FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) 
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return ["correctPass"=>true,"banned"=> ($userRow['status']== 1) ? true : false];
            }
            else
            {
                return ["correctPass"=>false];
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

    if(empty($uname) || empty($umail) || empty($upass)){
        $error = "Please enter all fields";
    }


    $validation = $login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass))
    if($validation["correctPass"])){
        if($validation["banned"]){
            $error = "User has been banned";
        }else{
            $success = "Logged in successfully, redirecting..";
            header( "refresh:3;url=debits" );
            //$login->redirect('debits');
        }
    }
    else{
        $error = "Incorrect username or password";
    }   
}
```

Comment: This works however after displaying the `User has been banned` message, I try to login again and it logs me in fine although my account is still in a banned state. If I refresh the page and try to login again it says i'm banned however as stated above, if I try login again straight after without refreshing it logs in.

Comment: When I move `$_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];` after `return ["correctPass"=>true,"banned"=> ..........` statement the issue I stated in the above comment does not apply however now does not set the session when I try to login

Comment: I removed the `$_SESSION` from the function and added it above `$success = "Logged in successfully ...... ";` and it worked.

Comment: @ZacRam If one of the answers here answers your question, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, every method of a class should have a single purpose. As you can see you are trying to get your method `doLogin()` to:

- fetch a row from the database
- verify the username and password combination
- verify the user is enabled/disabled
- set a session variable

You also want to keep each method **small**, in particular `public` methods. Usually when you're over just a few lines of code, you might want to break some of the functionality off into another method.

And one recommended way to [do form validation with multiple return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121318/oop-form-validation-without-using-multiple-return-types) is to throw an Exception containing the error message and then catch it later when you want to handle the error.

Might I instead suggest a bit of refactoring? (note, this is untested and may contain syntax errors)

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    $user = $this->fetchUserFromDatabase($uname, $umail);
    if ($user !== false || $this->isBanned($user)) {
        throw new Exception('This account has been banned');
    }
    elseif ($user === false || !$this->validatePassword($upass, $user)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid username or password combination');
    }
    $this->startSession($user['user_id']);
    return true;
}

private function fetchUserFromDatabase($uname, $umail)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass, status 
        FROM users
        WHERE user_name=:uname 
        OR user_email=:umail ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

private function isBanned(Array $user)
{
    return $user['status'] == 1;
}

private function validatePassword($upass, Array $user)
{
    return password_verify($upass, $user['user_pass'])
}

private function startSession($user_id)
{
    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $user['user_id'];
}
```

Then in your other file:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

    if(empty($uname) || empty($umail) || empty($upass)){
        $error = "Please enter all fields";
    }

    try {
        $login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass);
        $success = "Logged in successfully, redirecting..";
        header( "refresh:3;url=debits" );
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

On another note, you may want to consider [getting PDO errors to throw Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992795/set-pdo-to-throw-exceptions-by-default) instead of `try/catch` blocks for every single query. Doing it how you have it gets super tedious if you have more than just a couple of queries. You can then set a global exception handler to handle any `PDOException` thrown.